# Error Constructor parameter should be str using pillow, aiohttp and discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, discord.py, aiohttp

I've successfully been able to use this filter to blur an image via a URL using pillow however I cannot for the life of me figure out why I'm getting the error; "Constructor parameter should be str" whenever I use an attachment over a URL. Here is my code;

```py
import discord
import aiohttp
import aiofiles
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
from discord.ext import commands

    @commands.cooldown(1, 5)
    @commands.command()
    async def blur(self, ctx, url=None):
        if url is None:
            await ctx.message.attachments[0].save("image.png")
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as urlgrabber:
                if urlgrabber.status == 200:
                    file = await aiofiles.open('image.png', mode='wb')
                    await file.write(await urlgrabber.read())
                    await file.close()
        img = Image.open(str("image.png"))
        img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur()).save(str("image.png"))
        file = discord.File(str("image.png"))
        embed = objectfile.twoembed(f"{ctx.message.author}, image blurred!", "Blurry.")
        embed.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, file=file)
```

If anyone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this error is present, however I've solved the problem using is not.

````py
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5)
    @commands.command()
    async def blur(self, ctx, url=None):
        if url is None:
            if ctx.message.attachments[0] is not None:
                await ctx.message.attachments[0].save("image.png")
                img = Image.open("image.png")
                img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur()).save("image.png")
                file = discord.File("image.png")
                embed = objectfile.twoembed(f"{ctx.message.author}, image blurred!", "Blurry.")
                embed.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed, file=file)
                return
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as urlgrabber:
                if urlgrabber.status == 200:
                    file = await aiofiles.open('image.png', mode='wb')
                    await file.write(await urlgrabber.read())
                    await file.close()
        img = Image.open("image.png")
        img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur()).save("image.png")
        file = discord.File("image.png")
        embed = objectfile.twoembed(f"{ctx.message.author}, image blurred!", "Blurry.")
        embed.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, file=file)```
````